# Dúvida em "continue" (SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop)

Tags: python-3.x

Estou começando no python e não consigo descobrir o porquê do erro abaixo, poderiam me ajudar?

```
def SecretNumber():
    GotIt = False
    while GotIt == False:
        One = int(input("Type a number between 1 and 10: "))
        Two = int(input("Type another number between 1 and 10: "))

    if (One >= 1) and (One <= 10):
        if (Two >= 1) and (Two <= 10):
            print('Your secret number is: ' + str(One * Two))
            GotIt = True
            continue
        else:
            print('Incorrect second value!')
    else:
        print("Incorrect first value!")
    print("Try again!")
```

> *****File "cell_name", line 14 SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop*****

Comment: Você está chamando o `continue` fora de um laço de repetição. O fato do seu primeiro `if` estar com recuo menor que o `while` faz com que ele não pertença ao bloco lógico do laço de repetição e, assim, na linha que utiliza o `continue`, por consequência, também estará fora do laço - vale ressaltar que desta forma o seu laço de repetição é infinito porque `GotIt` nunca deixa de ser `False`.

Comment: É isso aí Osvaldo, como o Caio mensionou, o problema ocorre porque o continue funciona dentro de um laço de repetição, é o python identifica os blocos de códigos pela identação, no seu caso seu if ficou fora do bloco while, apenas de 4 espaços no seu bloco if completo e deve funcionar.